# Unrecognized services in Puppet Enterprise

Tags: puppet

I have tried to run the following:

`puppet resource service pe-puppetdb ensure=running`

and receive the error

`Error: Could not start Service[pe-puppetdb]: Execution of '/sbin/service pe-db start"' returned 1: Starting pe-db: [FAILED].`

```
service { 'pe-puppetdb':
   ensure => 'stopped',
}
```

I am also running into the same issue with puppetserver. I suspect this may be a certification issue, but wanted to run it by others.

Answer (score 0):

In Puppet Enterprise, the service is called `pe-puppetdb`, so the `puppet` command should be

```sh
puppet resource service pe-puppetdb ensure=running
```

Comment: yes I will edit, but I am actually unable to start the resource doing the following command. "Error: Could not start Service[pe-puppetserver]: Execution of '/sbin/service pe-puppetserver start"' returned 1: Starting pe-puppetserver; [FAILED]. 

This is a fairly cryptic message and im not sure how to parse it. I get the same message when running the command listed in your answer for pe-puppetdb.

Both indicate that the services are stopped.

Comment: The error message means that Puppet is failing to start the services because the underlying command `/sbin/service` is failing. Try running `/sbin/service pe-puppetserver start` from the command line - it should give a better error message. If not, you need to start looking through the system and puppetserver logs